# Voice call recording on Moto Phones

Tags: android, motorola-droid, audio-source, call-recording

I want to record voice for incoming and outgoing line during call. I have tried many solutions which otherwise work on devices other than Moto Phones(In my case I have tried on Moto E(2nd gen), Moto G5 and Moto C).
I have tried this two libraries:

1. [call-recorder-for-android](https://github.com/riul88/call-recorder-for-android)
   This library, first of all, crashese with following log trace

> 03-07 10:56:57.307 293-9261/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 4, sample rate 8000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, session 3494, flags 0
>   03-07 10:56:57.308 293-9261/? E/StagefrightRecorder: audio source is not initialized
>   03-07 10:56:57.309 7290-7290/com.callrecorder.android E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648
>   03-07 10:56:57.314 7290-7290/com.callrecorder.android E/Call recorder: Failed to set up recorder.
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
>                                                                              at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.callrecorder.android.RecordService.startRecording(RecordService.java:194)
>                                                                              at com.callrecorder.android.RecordService.onStartCommand(RecordService.java:92)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3028)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

According to official Android documentations

> Capturing from VOICE_CALL source requires the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.

So, I tried to change AudioSource to `AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION` which worked without crashing. But not able to record incoming voice. It only records outgoing voice. I've tried the same with `AudioSource.DEFAULT` but again no luck. It behaves same as `AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION`

2. [CallRecLib](https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib)

This library has some tweaks at NDK level. But that too have given the same result as above library with `AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION`

According to MOTO's official forum [this](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-G-MOTO-G-4G-LTE-1st-Gen/Call-Recorder-MOTO-G/td-p/3134604) discussion thread Motorola officials say that, they don't support VOICE CALL recording internally but some third party application may be able to do it. Which is actually right. [Automatic Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&hl=en) application in play store provides working solution for the same.
I am not able to find what kind of modifications it has done, which gave it a working solution.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: this issue in moto device i already face it. this only app from playstore is work well any other app not work.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boldbeast.recorder&hl=en

Comment: Yes, Automatic Call Recorder also uses some native code and it does not hold `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` permission. Give it a check with earphones.

Comment: You can try recording with `AudioSource,VOICE_COMMUNICATION` and setting volume to max during call. It is working on Moto G4 play.

Comment: User should be able to bear an incoming voice. So setting the volume to max is not an option. And i've tried `AudioSource,VOICE_COMMUNICATION` it doesn't work, it only records outgoing voice.

Comment: I know setting volume to max is not a smart option. Since, `AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION` also uses microphone to record audio, so voice coming from ear-piece must be loud enough that mic can capture it.